# Instagram style multimedia listview

Tags: android, listview, android-videoview

I've tried searching but not found a definitive answer. I would like to know the best way to create a listview that can display either audio/video view items with a media controller that the user can play/pause etc for each item. I assume implementing a texture view would be the way forward (i believe videoview doesn't play nice with scrollviews) but i'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: So, How you resolved your issue ?

Comment: No, still haven't found a good work around yet. I tried with texture views but it seemed to hit a wall. I went another way in the end (List of buttons that opens a separate video activity) but I would be very keen to learn how facebook/vine/instagram etc implement it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have not actually tried this myself, however I will give you my idea either way.

I would populate the listview using two different views. One for images, and another for video. Then in your adapter/Java code you would need to add a statement determining which view you would like to use to populate the listview with.

For example, you have two xml files:

`videolistview.xml`

`imagelistview.xml`

in your `MainActivity.java` file, you would alter your adapter to determine which file to reference in order to populate the listview.

Hopefully that made sense.